# Is reasonable right to privacy interpreted solely by policy, or are there limits within UK Law as to what is permitted?

Tags: united-kingdom, email, security, privacy

We have a Data Protection Officer who is quite senior; and should, on paper, know the intricacies of EU/UK Data Law. *However*, they often make questionable choices that are challenged by other colleagues, many much more experienced than the DPO.

Our DPO is also our CISO, and in response to a single employee (out of thousands) potentially exporting PII (accidentally) to a personal device, has asked for a policy that I find intrusive, and concerning. The CISO/DPO is notoriously dismissive and usually doesn't reply to emails/phonecalls; so before challenging the policy I would like to be sure of my position.

The request is to create a mail-flow monitoring  that would capture any emails sent externally containing a photograph, and BCC them into a mailbox monitored only by the DPO/CISO. Our employees would not be aware of this activity, and we would not be able to audit what the DPO/CISO has/has not seen in this mailbox (limitation of the technology).

Not only do I find this intrusive, I find the response entirely disproportionate to the actual incident.

**On what grounds, if any, do I have to challenge the intrusiveness of this?**

Are employee's entitled to any reasonable right to privacy within an organisation, within this context?

N.B, I do not have the option of approaching the DPO/CISO and discussing directly.

Comment: If you really want to kick up a fuss about this one, you need to talk to an actual lawyer. However, there seems to be a simple solution: use your work e-mail only for work purposes, then there's no problem. This is what you should be doing anyway, so...

Comment: You can get eveyone to attach benign images to every email they send ... that mailbox will be so full so fast he won’t know what hit him...  As you are in the UK you could check with Citizens Advice, but this is probaly a minefield and may end up in court to provide a Stated Case...

Comment: @PhilipKendall Even if work e-mail is only used for work purposes it may still contain a lot of personal data, some of it regulated by law. eg, name and address, tax affairs, reasons for absences, performance evaluations, etc. Can the company keep this secure? Do they process it only for legal reasons? Might the CISO use it to advance his power in the organisation, or for personal reasons? Can the company comply with subject access requests (presumably not whilst keeping it secret...)?

Comment: @AlexHayward Given that *all* the company e-mails, whether containing a photo or not, are almost certainly going to be stored on the servers somewhere, most of that is a different question.

Comment: (1) what is PII ?  (2) the idea of copying images seems utterly normal.  it's a work email.

Comment: Personal Identifiable Information.

Comment: "Our employees would not be aware of this activity" may be very relevant - depending on jurisdiction it may well be the case that this is permitted if people are properly informed about it, and absolutely illegal if (as in this case) you attempt to hide it from them.

Comment: @Peteris the Jurisdiction is the UK, and you are correct that not notifying them that it at least *may* be used for such purposes is illegal as per the Data Protection Act.

Comment: For example, a (the?) key ruling by European Court of Human Rights regarding monitoring of emails https://www.echr.coe.int/Documents/Press_Q_A_Barbulescu_ENG.PDF judged that Mr. Bărbulescu’s rights were violated mainly not because of what the company did with the emails, but that he wasn't properly notified about what they're going to do; that the lack of appropriate prior notice was what made those particular actions illegal.

Comment: why are they specifically targeting a photograph in an email.

Comment: @Neuromancer there are a few possibilities. The first is that the PII data in question was photographic by nature (eg: a document scan). Another is that they already have a keyword system in place to catch text-based exfiltration, which can be bypassed by using images instead. Given OP's description of the CISO, they sound like the kind that would implement measures that get in the way of productivity quite a lot, so some employees may try to find ways around what they perceive to be 'bullshit' measures, hence the use of pictures.

Comment: To cut to the heart of this confusing question.  *Some* companies *may* offer "private use of company email".  (In practice, almost no companies, and basically no large companies, do this.)   The OP should simply state if the company in question, offers private use of company email.

Comment: @520 good point I hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 2):

## There are many laws surrounding privacy; your employer monitoring your actions on work devices/services doesn't break any of them.

Your work devices and services are owned by your company and not you. Therefore they are the ones with the ultimate rights to do what they like with these devices/service, not you.

Your CISO/DPO made the right choice to make this a policy; while this may have been an incident with a single employee, that is enough to have your company screwed **hard** by GDPR among other privacy laws. The fines for being in breach of these laws are enough to end a company. You may also recall that the leakage of hundreds of thousands of taxpayers' PII (also in the UK) was *also* a case of a single employee doing something they shouldn't.

Most places tend to have the fact that they reserve the right to monitor device/service usage as they like in their Acceptable Usage Policy. This is probably something already in your contracts. They are not required to admit that they *actually* do this kind of monitoring.

Comment: all correct and straightforward

Answer (score 1):

In most companies, sending private emails, for example during your lunch break, is permitted. And even if you are not permitted to send private emails, private emails are still private emails. Most over the EU, reading your private emails (even those that you were not supposed to send) can get the company into trouble.

Collecting *all* my private email, without a specific reason, without telling me, and making them accessible to that one person, that's a massive intrusion of privacy, and if that happened at my company and I found out, there would be hell to pay.

Now Fattie's answer is different, but the question to the company and your DPO is: Do you feel lucky, punk?

Comment: The question isn't relating to *private* emails but emails sent from work email addresses, which your employer will have significantly more legal control over, even in the EU.

Comment: I can send private emails from my work email address. Maybe I shouldn't, but I can, and they are private, and if the DPO reads them and I find out, he is in trouble.

Comment: You can, but it will be subjected to the same monitoring as your work emails. The employer is not required to differentiate between work and personal emails (which would be an insane requirement for the business; how could they possibly work that out without monitoring or reading the emails in the first place?).

Comment: That's exactly the point: The employer does _not_ have the right to look at private email without a good reason. The "insane requirement" for the business is their problem, not mine. What this DPO suggests is ridiculous, _because_ of these problems.

Comment: "In most companies, sending private emails, for example during your lunch break, is permitted. "  This is wrong, Gnash.  (Obviously you can do that *on another email account, your own*.)  The overwhelming majority of companies do *not* offer private use of company email.  I even quoted the relevant EU regulations/law/whatever (in the EU, they never quite clarify "what any thing is", but there it is!)

Comment: "The employer does not have the right to look at private email without a good reason."

Making sure data isn't exfiltrated or viruses aren't being delivered via email is a pretty damn good reason, and dealing with those problems necessitates reading the emails, at least by automated software.

Answer (score 1):

**You are right to be concerned**

It strongly appears that your Data Protection Officer has a "conflict of interest" in the duties he is performing here.

To be specific, article 38(6) of the GDPR states:

"6. The data protection officer may fulfil other tasks and duties. The controller or processor shall ensure that any such
tasks and duties do not result in a conflict of interests."

https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=OJ:L:2016:119:FULL

And the supporting guidance from the ICO states:

"Basically this means the DPO cannot hold a position within your organisation that leads him or her to determine the purposes and the means of the processing of personal data."

https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/?template=pdf&patch=248#link19

For the avoidance of doubt, employee data is fully in scope for GDPR (article 88).

Essentially, the role of the DPO is to be an independent arbiter within your organisation. They should certainly not be rifling through photos sent by employees, and *definitely* not doing so alone in secret.

What you actually do about this (escalate to management / HR, or some other route) depends very much on your organisation. You might want to (without mentioning any of the decisions he has made or your concerns about them) simply highlight to him the organisational risk of the DPO not being independent, e.g.

"I was looking through an article on the GDPR the other day, and it said that the Data Protection Officer should be someone independent. I'm a bit concerned that we should make sure we have someone independent, so we don't get into any problems with audits", and maybe, if he is still dismissive, forward some of the quotes above.

Once you have an independent DPO in place, you can then raise your concerns about the specific policy *to them*.

Answer (score -1):

> Are employee's entitled to any reasonable right to privacy within an organisation, within this context?

There is absolutely no "personal privacy" concept related to "work email".

(Note that - apart from anything else - every single work email and communication is, of course obviously, stored and kept and can be reviewed at any time. Adding a flag for image items is no different.)

---

https://edps.europa.eu/data-protection/data-protection/reference-library/private-use-electronic-communications-workplace_en

It reads "**where** limited private use is allowed .. such and such" and "Limited private use of these tools is often **permitted**..."

There's absolutely no guarantee or even expectation that a particular company X will offer private use of company email.

Comment: You are wrong, in Europe you can have a reasonable expectation of privacy even if you use your work email for private communication.

Comment: I *believe* that is totally wrong, Mark.  The act reads "**where** limited private use is allowed .. such and such" and "Limited private use of these tools **is often** permitted..."  There's absolutely no guarantee or even expectation that a particular company X will offer private use of company email.  (Don't even mention that it is absolutely trivial to additionally have a private email.)

Comment: Well there is https://www.engadget.com/2017/09/05/european-court-work-email-monitoring/  ([judgement](https://hudoc.echr.coe.int/eng#{%22itemid%22:[%22001-177082%22]})) which at least requires upfront announcement of monitoring and scope of monitoring. And I believe there have been other cases.

Comment: yes, the OP does seem to be totally informed about the monitoring ...

Comment: That is true, but I believe there have been further cases refining what a company can and cannot do with the information collected through such monitoring. And on a related note, I vaguely recall a case in the Netherlands where the judgement was that given a lot of private/personal things can only be handled during office hours, employers cannot forbid reasonable private communication during working hours. I might be wrong on both though, as I haven't located good sources yet.

Comment: @Fattie regarding "the OP is informed". Did you notice the *"Our employees would **not be aware** of this activity,"* in the question?

Comment: hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ , I guess I wasn't clear enough.  (1) the law states there is *absolutely no need* for a company to offer private use of company email.  (2) as an everyday commonplace, most companies (indeed, almost all large companies) do *not* offer private use of company email.

Comment: Yeah, I don't disagree on that. But your statement "There is absolutely no "privacy" concept related to "work email"." may be misinterpreted. I would think the CEO or a manager responsible for signing financial contracts expect their emails not to be read by other employees, right? And most employees would expect their emails to HR or accountancy (which may contain sensitive and/or private info) to be read by relevant parties only. These are still privacy matters, related to work none the less.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm not sure what to say - (1) the quoted law (indeed, which you pointed me to) is simply clear as day  (2) the quoted judgement completely supports the situation at hand (3) moreover, it's simply an everyday commonplace that most companies (simply, ALL multinationals, large concerns) simply do not offer private use of company email.    I'll leave it to y'all, cheers

Comment: In the quote you give, you are confusing two different meanings of the word “private”. There is private in the sense of “not workplace-related”, and private in the sense of “for the recipient’s eyes only”. The former is meant here. It is a given that if personal use is allowed (explicitly or implicitly) there will be an expectation of privacy. Also, note, in some circumstances there can be an expectation of privacy even for work-related email, e.g. communications relating to harassment etc.

Comment: PS: The link you added, read in full, basically contradicts your answer, e.g. “minimise monitoring to the extent possible. For example, instead of monitoring individual usage, employers can monitor aggregate levels of usage and send general reminders to staff“

Comment: hi @JoeStevens , I'm, sorry I just can't agree.  (1) it couldn't be clearer  (2) it's an extremely commonplace, well-know, situation.   It's pointless repeating things on here; if you have any strong reference that describes what you assert, I would love to see it - cheers!

Comment: hi @JoeStevens , not at all, you are simply reading the part about *the unusual case where a company does permit private use of company email*.  Cheers for now

Comment: I did, see above. To say it again, read the link you added, and tell me with a straight face there is no expectation of confidentiality.

Comment: hi @JoeStevens, you are simply reading the part about the unusual case where a company does permit private use of company email. Cheers for now.   If the remarkable position you explain was the case, one could very easily find an article (indeed, zillions thereof) about the issue in Europe.  I leave it to you for further comments, cheers

Comment: It does not say “unusual”; it actually says “often”. Making up your own quote and putting it in italics shows you’ve already lost the argument, to be honest. You’ve been downvoted already, and think you know you’re wrong here, so I’ll leave it there.

Comment: @Fattie Ayaya, this is only confusing because the bureaucrats that run the EU are comically clueless :).  This whole 'privacy' thing will go out the window as soon as some company tries to get out of a GDPR violation by claiming they couldn't have prevented it because of GDPR.  Basically, privacy rules prevent them from enforcing privacy rules.

Comment: Joe, you can easily learn the literal definition of "often" and in the other example "where".  (Regarding the value of voting on this site - I can only assume you were joking  :)  )  @Johns-305 , yes, you make a good point that the whole thing is a shambles. The fundamental notion here is "So, in Europe, can companies assert that the company email is for business use only" , the answer, of course, it's a commonplace.

Comment: @Fattie, in this instance, Joe/ypercube/Mark are all correct to point out some assumptions you're operating under. Our employee handbook clearly states that use of personal email *is permitted*; but does not clarify whether 'personal' pertains to 'private', which is one of the points they are discussing.